# Turning OFF monitors removes it as device

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, remote-desktop, teamviewer

I have a dual monitor setup. I turn off the monitors when leaving to home. And remote it using Teamviewer, Teamviewer shows only single monitor and when I check the status of the other monitor using Device Manager it shows just one monitor. Based on other forums on TeamViewer it says that this is because I use DVI port and turning off monitors will remove them just like disabling a USB device hence the reason I am seeing  just one.

Is there any way to circumvent this issue? any settings that will still enable me to use both the monitors when they are turned off using TeamViewer?

Answer (score 0):

That is indeed correct. DVI devices will get unstalled when the monitor is turned off. Teamviewer has the ability to install a mirror driver.

Installing that should fix the issue.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/Ca20qWr.png

Comment: this driver turns the monitors to black screens when remoted in, am I correct? The installation failure seems to be a common problem among many. I read somewhere that it is because the digital signature has expired.

Comment: You need to install the driver while the monitor is turned on. But it should then remember the resolution while the monitor is turned off.

Comment: Is there any other source from where I can download these drivers? I simply cannot seem to install using the teamviewer itself. Also, my monitors are turned ON, I am working on them right now.

Comment: Installing the mirror drivers is something you must do from TeamViewer itself inside the advanced menu. If it fails, restart teamviewer as administrator.